# How to change <input type ="file"> style change

Tags: css, forms

I want to change the design of the `<input type="file">` like the image below. Please guide me how I can change this.

[image: File button image]

Comment: you need to hide the actual input element and style its label like you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.upload-file {
display:flex;
align-items: center;
padding: 20px;
heignt: 100px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.upload-file span {
color: #898989;
flex-grow:1;
}
.upload-button {
background-color: blue;
color:white;
border-radius:50px;
padding:10px 30px;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
font-size:14px;
}
.upload-button input[type="file"] {
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-file">
<span>No file selected.</span>
<button class="upload-button">Browse <input type="file"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks vinay choudhary it's working.

Comment: When i apply this code in contact form 7 the button is working like input type submit dont show file uplaoad  option

Comment: https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/fEdrz so you can check here also